# How to share data between two different component in angular for different module

Tags: angular, typescript

**How to share data in between 2 different component for 2 different module.**

I have 2 module dashboard and preference and two component dashboard.component.ts and preference.component.ts respectively

I have created bar.service.ts service to pass data and my service contains below code

```
private messageSource = 'orderView';

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource = message;
  }
```

preference.component.ts contains below code

```
this.bar.changeMessage('groupByView');
```

dashboard.component.ts contains below code

```
console.log(this.bar.messageSource);
```

I am using routing and preference display preference page and dashboard display dashboard page.

When user is on preference page and change messageSource to groupByView, it is not reflecting on dashboard page.

**Dashboard page always contains orderView value in messageSource**

Comment: Are the ```changeMessage``` and ```console.log``` in sync context?

Comment: @BálintRéthy means ?

Comment: It means if you call console.log first and changeMessage after that even in async context (for example a random click event) then it will write orderView on the console

Answer (score 1):

You can use observables (they are highly integrated into Angular).

The service (YourService):

```
@Injectable() // { providedIn: 'root' } ? read below
export class YourService {
  messageSourceSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('orderView');
  messageSource: Observable<string> = this.messageSourceSubject.asObservable();

    publishMessage(message: string): void {
      this.messageSourceSubject.next(message);
    }
}
```

Your service must be registered in root service (`providedIn` property of Injectable or you have to put this service into some providers (probably your root module).

Your components:

When you need to get data in TypeScript (in the component TS code), you need:

```
constructor(public yourService: YourService) {
  this.yourService
    .messageSource
    .subscribe(message => console.log(message));
  // don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy (`subscription.unsubscribe` - subscribe returns it) or `pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))` - takeUntil is an RxJS operator from `rxjs/operators`.
}
```

If you need it in HTML:

```
<div>{{ yourService.messageSource | async }}</div>
```

`async` keyword is an AsyncPipe (from CommonModule from `@angular/common`). If you use AsyncPipe you don't need to unsubscribe anywhere, it will handle it by itself.

Also, if you use subscription in the component you must not forget about unsubscribing (I gave some comments in the code above)

Don't forget about importing all stuff into your component.

Also, if you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your components, you have to say to Angular to run change detection on this component in some future. It can be done using `ChangeDetectorRef` dependency (you can get it through DI) and its method `markForCheck`.

Comment: I tried the same before but it was also not working, so just removed observable and make it simple

Comment: Then, you have to provide more context. Probably, some repro. I also updated the answer with text about change detection strategy. Angular does not work the way you describing in your question. It is a bit more complicated.

Comment: okay i think i am doing some mistake here
"Your service must be registered in root service (providedIn property of Injectable or you have to put this service into some providers (probably your root module)."

Comment: can you please clarify my comments what exactly i need to do

Comment: I have passed this inside my preference module providers: [BarService]

Comment: What module providers? What is your module structure? Do you have dashboard, preference and application modules? Did you provide YourService into providers of the application module? I assume it is root module in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subject

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdfsp1)

Bar Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class BarService {

// Observable string sources
  private messageSource = new Subject<string>();
  messageSource$ = this.messageSource.asObservable();


  constructor() { }


  changeMessage(message: string) {
     this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

Prefrence Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarService } from '../bar.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-preference',
  templateUrl: './preference.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preference.component.css']
})
export class PreferenceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private barService: BarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onChange() {
    this.barService.changeMessage(`Update dashboard at ${ new Date()}`)
  }

}
```

Prefrence Template:

```
<p>
preference works! 
<button (click)="onChange()">Update Dashboard</button>
</p>
```

Dashboard Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarService } from '../bar.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  changeMessage: any;
 constructor(private barService: BarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barService.messageSource$.subscribe((res)=>{
      this.changeMessage = res;
    });
  }

}
```

Dashboard Template:

```
<p>
dashboard works! {{changeMessage}}
</p>
```

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately when i go to preference page and then dashboard page this is not triggered  this. barService.messageSource$.subscribe((res)=>{
       console.log(res);
    });

Comment: it triggered atleast in case of BehaviorSubject

Comment: is there any difference when we have 2 different module passing data between components

Comment: injected service on root  means ?

Comment: ‘root’ means that we want provide the service at the root level

Comment: i simply called the service like you did inside constructor and nothing else

Comment: i have passed this also providers: [BarService]